# Thymeleaf java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string Long I don't know

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

Controller

```java
@GetMapping("/department/list/{departId}/edit")
public String updateForm(@CurrentUser Account account,
                         @PathVariable("departId") Department department,
                         Model model) {

   model.addAttribute(account);
   model.addAttribute(modelMapper.map(department, DepartForm.class));
        return "department/edit";
   }

   @PostMapping("/department/list/{departId}/edit")
   public String updateFormSubmit(@CurrentUser Account account,
                                  @PathVariable("departId") Department department,
                                  @Valid DepartForm departForm, Errors errors, Model model) {

      if (errors.hasErrors()) {
          model.addAttribute(account);
          model.addAttribute(department);
          return "department/edit";
      }

      departmentService.updateDepart(modelMapper.map(departForm, Department.class), account);

      return "redirect:/department/detail";
  }
```

Domain

```java
@Entity
@Getter @Setter @EqualsAndHashCode(of="id")
public class Department {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    ...
```

DTO

```java
@Data
public class DepartForm {

   private Long id;

   ...
}
```

Thymeleaf

```html
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <form class="col-sm-10"
          th:action="@{/department/list/{departId}/edit}"  th:object="${departForm}" method="post" novalidate>
        <div class="form-group">
           <label for="departId">number</label>
           <input id="departId" type="text" th:field="*{id}" class="form-control"
                       placeholder="name" readonly>
        </div>

...
```

Error Message

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "{departId}"
...

Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Long] for value '{departId}'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "{departId}"
```

I've got to write code to save and edit the department to the this error occurred.
I don't know What is a problem ... DOT and DOMAIN are both `Long` type. But
for input string error occurs.
Where is it recognized as a string?
`th:action="@{/department/list/{departId}/edit}"`
I think it's this problem.

Comment: `@PathVariable("departId") Department department` in your controller's method's parameters is it correct? Can you try changing it to `@PathVariable("departId") Long departId` and load the department by querying the database via `departmentService` and `departId`?

Comment: @pleft oh... Thanks for your help. When i use the ModelMapper to DTO -> Entity, i thought you should have a `Department` when using `@PathVariable.`